# Вывести 3 рандомных числа из массива

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня есть две таблицы. В одной таблице `id` пользователей, в другой `id` пользователей, которых функция рандома не должна вызвать. Надо вывести 3 рандомных не повторяющихся числа из переменной `$allowed`.

```
$banned = "SELECT id FROM admin";

$allowed = "SELECT id FROM 10a WHERE id NOT IN (". $banned .")";
```

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() ?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 2):

Простейший вариант, который судя по названию таблицы `10a` (школа?), Вам подойдёт:

```
SELECT id
FROM 10a
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM admin)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

Недостаток этого варианта - логарифмическое замедление при увеличении количества строк в таблице `10a`, так как `ORDER BY RAND()` вызывает сканирование и затем сортировку всей таблицы целиком - и без использования индексов.

Вот [здесь](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) и [здесь](https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) всё это неплохо расписано.

Вариант для больших таблиц, который мне кажется предпочтительным, это вставка в таблицу дополнительного индексированного `float` столбца `rnd`, в который при создании строки записывается результат функции `RAND()`. В этом случае рандомизация выполняется на этапе заполнения таблицы, а при выборке мы случайным образом определяем начальное значение столбца `rnd` и выполняем чтение нужного количества строк, отсортированных по `rnd`.

Пример на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xaQHX1vNm6iRUsoGauJqHM/0). Схемы таблиц и запрос - ниже:

```
CREATE TABLE 10a (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name text,
  rnd float,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE admin (
  id INT
);

CREATE TRIGGER 10a_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON 10a
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.rnd = RAND();

CREATE INDEX rnd_idx ON 10a(rnd);
```

Заметьте, что в запросе 2 раза встречается число 3 - количество возвращаемых значений. Это сделано для того, чтобы "неудачники" с 3 самыми большими значениями `rnd` имели равновероятный шанс попасть в выдачу, как и все остальные

```
SELECT r.*
FROM 
( 
    SELECT RAND() * 
    (
        SELECT rnd
        FROM 10a
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM admin)
        ORDER BY rnd DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
    ) start
) init
JOIN 10a r
WHERE r.rnd > init.start
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM admin)
ORDER BY r.rnd
LIMIT 3;
```